# Pandemic - how many epidemic cards?

Tags: pandemic

We've got the 2013 edition of Pandemic, and the four of us are struggling! For instance, it says to prepare the Player Deck by using 4, 5, or 6 Epidemic cards for an Introductory, Standard, or Heroic game. We keep losing on 4.

To get some help, I watched the Youtube video from Tabletop Episode 14 for  Pandemic - which uses the older version - and they seemed to suggest starting with just 2 Epidemic cards. I know I'm an adult, so I can do what I want really - but is the 4 Epidemic cards in 2013 too hard for newbies?

Comment: Note that 4 player is harder than 3 player, which is harder than 2 player.

Comment: 4 epidemics is usually pretty easy. Read the rules carefully and check you haven't missed something important. Trying to eradicate all 4 diseases is a common misunderstanding, you only have to find the cures to win the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I think 4 is a great number for an easy game.** If you find yourself running out of cards in the player deck, then you should really evaluate how you use those cards during the game. Discarding cards to take a flight shouldn't be done too frequently since that depletes that resource used to cure the disease. Also, work together to Share Knowledge, even though it can be challenging since you have to be in the same city as the card. Hopefully, you are playing with roles that negate some of the drawbacks I described above. If you are still having trouble, try playing with 3 and see what that does for you. After while, you'll start to get the hang of the game, and will look forward to the challenge that 4, 5, or 6 epidemic cards adds to the game.

Answer (score 2):

I just played that a couple days ago, and it wasn't too hard. What causes you to lose the game most often?

Are you running out of cubes of 1 color? Try to get someone there are soon as possible (even burning a card), maybe dropping a research station so others can come as well.

Are you running out of cards? Try to wait on disease cubes until 2-3 on a city and focus on getting the cure/cards to a curer.

Comment: The best we've done - in about 5 plays - is to find the cure for two diseases, but it's running out of cards in the Player Deck that finishes us off.

Comment: @PeterSchofield Assuming you're curing not eradicating, the next most common mistake might be trying to treat diseases too much, instead of letting them spread a bit while you exchange cards. As long as you're not risking outbreaks or running out of cubes, you can get away with leaving some cubes on the board.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question and just appears to ask questions about how the OP is playing the game.